# regex performance degrades

Tags: c#, regex, performance

I'm writing a C# application that runs a number of regular expressions (~10) on a lot (~25 million) of  strings.  I did try to google this, but any searches for regex with "slows down" are full of tutorials about how backreferencing etc. slows down regexes. I am assuming that this is not my problem because my regexes start out fast and slow down.

For the first million or so strings it takes about 60ms per 1000 strings to run the regular expressions. By the end, it's slowed down to the point where its taking about 600ms. Does anyone know why?

It was worse, but I improved it by using instances of `RegEx` instead of the cached version and compiling the expressions that I could.

Some of my regexes need to vary e.g. depending on the user's name it might be 
`mike said (\w*)` or `john said (\w*)`

My understanding is that it is not possible to compile those regexes and pass in parameters (e.g `saidRegex.Match(inputString, userName)`).

Does anyone have any suggestions?

[Edited to accurately reflect speed - was per 1000 strings, not per string]

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: It is very hard to give more advice, if you have taken the usual measures to improve performance. If it is OK, can you show your regex?

Comment: It's unlikely that the regex engine itself is slowing down. More likely is that your application is saving results, so memory is growing, and this is causing overall performance to degrade. Monitor your process memory size. Also check for memory leaks.

Comment: Also, how are you determining that the RegEx itself is the source of the slowness?  Are you doing anything else in the loop that might also be to blame, such as retrieving the "current" string, etc.?

Comment: I was retrieving the current string and that was killing me.  I'm not doing it any more.  I am storing results, but when I run the performance profiler it's still blaming the regular expressions as being the worst offenders.  Give me a moment and I'll post some regexes with the identifying stuff removed.

Thanks for the quick replies!

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: My worst performing regex is created like this
`var myRegex = new Regex(string.Format("{0}.*(?:and spent|and paid).*[\\$£](\\d+[\\.,]?\\d{{0,2}})", Regex.Escape(playerName)),
                    RegexOptions.None);`
I run it on strings like "Mike went into the supermarked and spent $1.57"

I want to know if Mike did the spending and how much he spent.

Comment: So you've got 10 different regexes (multiplied by number of "players"?) each run against all 25M strings?  Could you flip this around to pull the relevant fields out of each string (thereby only retrieving it once) and then do a smaller subset of matching?

Comment: Sorry, to be more clear - at the point where I run this regex, I already know the players in this string's game.  This means there are only 2-3 players, whose names I know, to be compared against a given string.  I tried looking for `(/w*)(?:and spent|and paid).*[\\$£](\\d+[\\.,]?\\d{{0,2}})` then matching the first capturing group to the known names, but it was significantly slower.

Comment: @Barmar I've run a thorough profile and the memory use is remaining static, so it's not a leak.  Good suggestion though.

Comment: @mike1952 - Can you post the whole code of your loop?  Just because the regex is the slowest part of the code overall, doesn't mean that it's the cause of the decreasing performance.

Comment: I can't really post the code directly - I can obfuscate it a bit then post something similar.  What suggests it's the problem is that at the start the profiler tells me that the regex constructor is taking 37% of the time.  By the end, it's taking 50% of the time.  The rate of degradation is also variable.  Sometimes it barely degrades (30-50%), while other times it's more severe (100-200%).

Comment: What a trip on the wayback machine, Im stuck in CPSC 321 again...Algorithms and Optimization.  So many BigO questions!!...Basically you need to look into either reducing the number of loop iterations, or reducing the number of Actual operations performed.  At the same time, keep an eye on memory size, re-use variables when you can.  Sorry I can't offer more advise, totally not helpful.  Good luck (definitely watching the question)

Comment: Finally, before I go home and make a futile attempt to sleep, there seems to be a drop in CPU usage over the course of the run - I start off around 50% (6 physical cores, 12 logical cores, so about what you would expect) and it then seems to drop to around 30ish.  Sometimes.  I think.  It takes 40 minutes to run, so it's hard to get statistical significance :).  I'm going to write a simpler version tomorrow morning, see if the problem is still there and then post that code.  Thanks all for your help.

Comment: Did you profile memory usage further? Can you check if GC is happening quite often or Gen2 is growing?
It could be possible that as your regex's run, less and less memory is left or memory is getting fragmented (usage of large objects)?

Comment: If the CPU is going below 100% (on a core, 50% for a dual core, etc) after a while then you are probably running into paging. Have you checked the memory consumption of your process in task manager?

Comment: Reading all the comments, it sounds like the 37% slowness is coming from the ***regexp compilation***, i.e. converting the regexp string to a FSA (Finite-State-Automaton) rather than from the regexp matches.

I'm not familiar with C#/.Net, but in perl there's an optimization where a regexp compilation is not repeated within loops unless that expression changes.

Would it be possible to construct the regexp's outside the inner loop and (only 10 expressions) and then do the inner loop (25 M passes) on the already constructed regexp's?

This may give you a nice boost (if possible).

Comment: Have you tried to use the RegEx static methods?

Comment: can you compile all of the player names into your pattern (since at the time of regex execution you know them all), in the vein of `(Mike|Jack|...)<remainder_of_regex>` ? simplifying the regex for optimistic matching weeding out the false positives might help, eg. `(/w*)(?:and spent|and paid).*[\\$£](\\d+[\\.,]?\\d{{0,2}})` -> `(Mike|Jack|...)([^\\$£.]+)[\\$£]` ? (the symbol `.` in capture group 2 exists to prevent matches of excessive length, ie. crossing sentence boundaries. replace/complement with other/more suitable character(s). on matching success, check capt. group 2 for proper content.

Comment: a last one: if your running time is superlinear, can you section the set of test strings into portions treated individually ? naive computation: running time n^2, split set into 2 halves, expect total savings of n^2/2. the trade-off is against the additional overhead for setting up your data structures twice.

Comment: I'd look at memory usage.  Which makes since that the process starts off fast, and strings build up in memory the process starts to slow.

Comment: It could very well be the garbage collector getting in the way. I found when doing something similar that changing to the server garbage collector cut GC time from about 80% to about 10%. Just add `<gcServer enabled="true"/>` to your app.config.

Comment: You might also consider changing that regex so that it's non-greedy. The `.*` is going to go to the end of the string and start backtracking. Replacing it with `.*?` might give you a pretty good boost. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3206d374.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may not be a direct answer to your question about RegEx performance degradation - which is somewhat fascinating. However - after reading all of the commentary and discussion above - I'd suggest the following:

Parse the data once, splitting out the matched data into a database table. It looks like you're trying to capture the following fields:

```
Player_Name | Monetary_Value
```

If you were to create a database table containing these values per-row, and then catch each new row as it is being created - parse it - and append to the data table - you could easily do any kind of analysis / calculation against the data - without having to parse 25M rows again and again (which is a waste).

Additionally - on the first run, if you were to break the 25M records down into 100,000 record blocks, then run the algorithm 250 times (100,000 x 250 = 25,000,000) - you could enjoy all the performance you're describing with no slow-down, because you're chunking up the job.

In other words - consider the following:

1. Create a database table as follows:

   ```
   CREATE TABLE PlayerActions (
       RowID          INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
       Player_Name    VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
       Monetary_Value MONEY       NOT NULL
   )
   ```
2. Create an algorithm that breaks your 25m rows down into 100k chunks. Example using LINQ / EF5 as an assumption.

   ```
   public void ParseFullDataSet(IEnumerable<String> dataSource) {
       var rowCount = dataSource.Count();
       var setCount = Math.Floor(rowCount / 100000) + 1;

       if (rowCount % 100000 != 0)
           setCount++;

       for (int i = 0; i < setCount; i++) {
           var set = dataSource.Skip(i * 100000).Take(100000);
           ParseSet(set);
       }
   }

   public void ParseSet(IEnumerable<String> dataSource) {
       String playerName = String.Empty;
       decimal monetaryValue = 0.0m;

       // Assume here that the method reflects your RegEx generator.
       String regex = RegexFactory.Generate();

       for (String data in dataSource) {
           Match match = Regex.Match(data, regex);
           if (match.Success) {
               playerName = match.Groups[1].Value;

               // Might want to add error handling here.
               monetaryValue = Convert.ToDecimal(match.Groups[2].Value);

               db.PlayerActions.Add(new PlayerAction() {
                   // ID = ..., // Set at DB layer using Auto_Increment
                   Player_Name = playerName,
                   Monetary_Value = monetaryValue
               });
               db.SaveChanges();

               // If not using Entity Framework, use another method to insert
               // a row to your database table.
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. Run the above one time to get all of your pre-existing data loaded up.
4. Create a hook someplace which allows you to detect the addition of a new row. Every time a new row is created, call:

   ```
   ParseSet(new List<String>() { newValue });
   ```

   or if multiples are created at once, call:

   ```
   ParseSet(newValues); // Where newValues is an IEnumerable<String>
   ```

Now you can do whatever computational analysis or data mining you want from the data, without having to worry about performance over 25m rows on-the-fly.

Comment: Note: The above code was written without compiling - so I don't guarantee that it works as-is, but it should lead you the right direction, if you choose to implement a solution as described.

Answer (score 0):

Regex does takes time to compute. However, U can make it compact using some tricks.
You can also use string functions in C# to avoid regex function.

The code would be lengthy but might improve performance.
String has several functions to cut and extract characters and do pattern matching as u need. 
like eg: IndeOfAny, LastIndexOf, Contains....

```
string str= "mon";
string[] str2= new string[] {"mon","tue","wed"};

if(str2.IndexOfAny(str) >= 0)
{
  //success code//
}
```